# How to select specific columns and rows from a CSV dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dataset

SAMPLE DATASET:

```
A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2

2  4   5  6  7  3

4  6   7  3  0  1

3  4   5  3  2  8
```

What if I want to import the dataset in the form of (2, 3) where The number accompanying the letter is one dimension and the letters are part of the same 'channel' are the other so that each row will be reconstructed into a batch like:

```
   1  2       1 2     1 2
A  2  4     A 4 6   A 3 4
B  5  6     B 7 3   B 5 3
C  7  3 ,   C 0 1 , C 2 8
```

Each row will turn into a batch making turning it into a (3,2,3) array. I am not melting them togheter becuase I want to keep each row as its own batch.

I am workign with eeg data.
Each row is a batch.

My idea is to grab the specific number of columns in each row but I am not sure how to do this I am not very experienced with working with CSV data.

Comment: What should happen to the other rows in the input?

Comment: IIUC use `for k, v in pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['A','B','C'], i='index', j='new').T.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    
    out = v.droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: @mozway they will go into there own (2,3) batches so that it will be (3,2,3)

Comment: @SCPCONTAINMENT another approach `tmp = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['A','B', 'C'], i='index', j='j') ; out = {i: tmp.loc[i].rename_axis(None).T for i in df.index}`

Comment: Or, if the columns are already sorted as A1/A2/B1/B3…, with numpy: `df.to_numpy().reshape(len(df),-1,3).swapaxes(-2, -1)`

Comment: @mozway i have updated my question to make it more clear.